# Проблема с добавлением проектов в gitlab ci

Tags: git, debian, oauth, gitlab

Конфигурация системы

```
    System information
    System:     Ubuntu 15.04
    Current User:   git
    Using RVM:  no
    Ruby Version:   2.1.2p95
    Gem Version:    2.2.2
    Bundler Version:1.7.4
    Rake Version:   10.4.2
    Sidekiq Version:3.3.0
    GitLab information
    Version:    7.14.3
    Revision:   d321305
    GitLab Shell
    Version:    2.6.5
    Gitlav CI Version: 7.8.4
```

Конфигурация до недавнего времени работала и проблем не возникало.
В данный момент при добавлении в gitlab ci нового проекта вылетает ошибка:

```
   Cannot save project
```

Начал разбираться в чем может быть проблема и наткнулся на ошибку при переходе на callback-url самого CI

```
  http://ci.example.com/user_sessions/callback
```

вылетает 500 ошибка при этом в production.log пишет

> OAuth2::Error (invalid_grant: The provided authorization grant is invalid, expired, revoked, does not match the redirection URI used in
>   the authorization request, or was issued to another client.
>   {"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"The provided
>   authorization grant is invalid, expired, revoked, does not match the
>   redirection URI used in the authorization request, or was issued to
>   another client."}):
>   app/controllers/user_sessions_controller.rb:18:in `callback'

Попробовал удалить его в Gitlab и создал новый токен во вкладке Application - толку ноль. Перезапуск служб не помогает. Что с ним могло случится?

Answer (score 1):

Такие вопросы наверное лучше задавать в [баг трекере](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ci/issues).

Учитывая что начиная с версии 8.0 gitlab и gitlab-ci объединили, имеет смысл обновиться до актуальной версии ([8.2](https://about.gitlab.com/2015/11/22/gitlab-8-2-released/)).